# Jenkins Android Emulator Plugin - "Could not create Android emulator: Failed to parse AVD config file"

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, jenkins, android-emulator, android-emulator-plugin

I'm struggling to find a recent sdk version that has Google APIs installed that will work with the Jenkins Android Emulator plugin. I'm sure they exist, but I can't figure out what the right `Android OS Version` parameter to configure the plugin is.

`Google Inc.:Google APIs:9` is the example they provide, so I change it to `Google Inc.:Google APIs:19`, `Google Inc.:Google APIs:25`, `Google Inc.:Google APIs:26`, and none of them work.

I've been trying to get the x86 target api to work, but my Jenkins instances run in AWS, where I don't believe hardware acceleration works, so x86 may not be an option.

**Please tell me the right `Android OS Version` parameter to use with Google APIs for Android SDK 19, 25, and 26, and please recommend an ABI to use with AWS.**

[image: Jenkins Android Emulator Plugin OS Version]

Comment: Sorry for the noise (I deleted my answer): the point was: I did consider the plugin, but I did not find using the Android Emilator outside AWS Mobile Hub documented at all. So when you say your Jenkins is on AWS, is it on the right kind of AWS (one which does expect an Android emulator)? That is what my answer was trying to address.

Comment: What happens when you run `android list target` like suggested in the text?